# What is good approach in storing price changes of a product / currency?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am building a system where users can own a currency pretty much like crypto. The idea is that the value of that currency changes every 24 hours based on certain factors.

Here's an example. There's a currency called "Coin" (CurrencyName) with an initial value of $1. The value changes every 24 hours, say the next day it becomes "$1.14". What's the best approach to record daily price? Should I create a "Value" column in the Currency Table and just update it every 24 hours while also updating another table say "Value History Table" for historical record?

**User Table**

- UserId INT PK
- Email VARCHAR(255)
- Password VARCHAR(255)

**Currency Table**

- CurrencyId INT PK
- CurrecyName VARCHAR(255)
- TotalSupply INT

**Inventory Table**

- CurrencyId INT FK
- UserId INT FK
- AmountOwned INT

Comment: If using MariaDB you can also use [system versioned tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/) that provide a historical record in the same table.

Comment: 2 tables:  Current and History.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70638923/1766831

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a datetime column to the `Currency` table:

```
+-------+------------+---------+
| CCode | PDate      | Price   |
+-------+------------+---------+
|   USD | 2022-01-09 | 1.00000 |
|   CHF | 2022-01-09 | 1.10712 |
|   EUR | 2022-01-09 | 1.22714 |
```

Also add another table with current actual prices:

```
+-------+---------+
| CCode | Price   |
+-------+---------+
|   USD | 1.00000 |
|   CHF | 1.10712 |
|   EUR | 1.22714 |
```

This table should have UNIQUE index for CCode column and should be inserted with
`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Price = NewPrice;`

N.B.
Do not use `VARCHAR(255) if you don't really need 255 characters.

Comment: Just to confirm, so the currency table is where I place the historical price of the currencies? On your example, it adds three entries (USD, CHF, EUR) on a daily basis? Then the additional table is as what you said, it updates and reflects the current price. Did I understand it right?

Comment: @Mikuro Yes, you have two tables - one for historical data and one for current values, because `groupwise MAX` is a pretty heavy operation that can slow down reporting significantly. You can make a various reports from historical data on a non-regular basis and a fast report for "current account state".

Comment: I see. Thank you so much.

Comment: Btw, my Inventory table references the CurrencyId on the Currency Table. Does that mean I should now instead reference it to the new table you suggested with the current actual prices?